# Iron-router _id after url

Tags: url, path, meteor, iron-router

I am using Iron-router and everything works fine. Changing urls goes nicely from within the app, but if I enter the url directly in the navigation toolbar of the browser, it gives an extra string.

For instance **/home** becomes **/home#.UwPUPc6AnwX**

```
Router.map( function () {
this.route('home', {
    data: function() {
        Session.set('cmsPage', 0);
    }
});
this.route('home2', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'home',
    data: function() {
        Session.set('cmsPage', 0);
    }
});
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please indicate which browser you are using and show the relevant router code.

Comment: This problem is showing up in all browsers.

Comment: @RienDaamen I tried using this code and I cannot get the behaviour you are getting under any browser (FF, Chrome, WKNightly or Safari)

Comment: BTW, I think you should move your session-altering code to `before` hook of your router controllers instead of using `data` which basically serves another purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the part which generates the strange URL. It's the 'Addthis' library placed in the head section.

```
    <!-- messes up the URL -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52e579bc6a1e3f4c"></script>
```